# Method to manage "NAN" (in capital letters) with Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nan

do you know if there is a way to manage the "NAN" all in capital letters present in a data file with Pandas?

I have some data files have this format:

```
"2020-08-14 14:00:00",10,154.9554,153.6879,154.3988,158.5282,"NAN","NAN",158.43,"NAN",155.2103
```

`.isnull()` and `.isna()` functions don't handle when "NAN" is capitalized but handle it when it is written this way "NaN" or "nan".

Thank you in advance, I looked for other topics but nothing on this specific subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isnull` and `isna` do **NOT** return True for strings, no matter the case.

Most likely you have a mix of real NaN and of strings:

```
s = pd.Series([float('nan'), 'NAN', 'nan', 'NaN'])
df = pd.concat({'s': s, 'isnull': s.isnull(), 'isna': s.isna()}, axis=1)
```

output:

```
     s  isnull   isna
0  NaN    True   True
1  NAN   False  False
2  nan   False  False
3  NaN   False  False
```

Now, by default, [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) recognizes the following strings as NaN:

```
'', '#N/A', '#N/A N/A', '#NA', '-1.#IND', '-1.#QNAN',
'-NaN', '-nan', '1.#IND', '1.#QNAN', '<NA>', 'N/A',
'NA', 'NULL', 'NaN', 'n/a', 'nan', 'null'
```

You can add `"NAN"` with the `na_values` option:

```
df = pd.read_csv(..., na_values=['NAN'])
```

Comment: Perfect 'df = pd.read_csv(..., na_values=['NAN'])' option is the best option in my case, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might simply use `.replace` as follows

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1.5,2.5,"NAN",3.5,4.5,"NAN",6.5,7.5]})
print(df.x.mean())  # TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
df.replace("NAN",float("nan"),inplace=True)
print(df.x.mean())  # 4.333333333333333
```

or if you wish to have new `pandas.DataFrame` with NAN-string replaced with "true" NaNs

```
df2 = df.replace("NAN",float("nan"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `.replace()` to assign `nan` values, and then you can use them as proper `nan`:

```
df["column"].replace({"NAN": np.nan})
```